# How to add more outdoor weather sensors to Software Defined Radio (Weather Station)

Tags: meteorology, earthquakes

How to add more outdoor weather sensors to Software Defined Radio (Weather Station) ?

I am looking for seismographic outdoor radio sensors to work for Software Defined Radio (Weather Station).

So frankly speaking I need to modify the existing outdoor radio sensors to detect seismography.

Most smartphones come with accelerometer sensors but it's hard to have smartphone to be operated outdoor or to be burried in the ground in your backyard.

Let me know your working solution to my problem

There is a nice question and answer from the past but I am looking for working hardware / software solution

"
Detecting seismic waves using Software Defined Radio

I understand about physic and waves, but I am a totally rookie in this topic. I was wondering which are the typical frequency ranges of the S-waves, P-waves and surface waves. My idea would be to detect any seismic event using Software Defined Radio, but I am not sure at all If ...
asked Aug 20, 2016 at 21:44 by Cod1ngFree